# unload in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a client register startup script like so:

> " " +
>                                       "document.body.onunload =
>   clearSession; " +
>                                   "";

The script works fine in IE8 by calling the clearSession() client script but not with firefox. can anyone help please?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.onunload` instead?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload